# Couldn't Attach .xls File Email Intent -Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I am creating a .xls file and saving it to the Downloads folder. I am trying to send the .xls file as an email attachment. However, when Gmail opens up I get a toast error message that says Couldn't Attach File. This error message is coming from Gmail. I have verified that the file is being created properly. I am not sure why it's not attached to the email.

Here is the code that creates the file and emailIntent.

```
 try{
           String nowDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";
            File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/"+"ExcelFile_"+nowDateTime+".xls");

            if(!filePath.exists()){
                filePath.createNewFile();
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            hssfWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);

            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
            Log.e("FilePath", filePath.toString());
            Log.e("Uri", uri.toString());
            emailIntent.setType("application/excel");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.Email_Subject_Line));
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            this.startActivity(emailIntent);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("GraphReportDialog", "Creating Excel Sheet File Output Stream Error "+ e.getMessage());
        }
```

Manifest Permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` has been useless for five years, as `file://` `Uri` values are banned on Android 7.0 and higher. You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. Please use `FileProvider` instead of `Uri.fromFile()`. See [this book section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) for more information and samples of using `FileProvider` in an Android app.

Answer (score 1):

CommonsWare was correct about using FileProvider. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) says Uri.fromFile() is less secure than FileProvider.

Once I added 3 main things, it worked as expected.
The first thing is adding providers in the manifest file:

```
   <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.counter"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                />
        </provider>
```

The second thing is adding the paths. I created another directory in my res file called xml. I then added an xml file called provider_paths.xml. Here is that code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path <!-- there are several different types of paths to use see the documentation-->
        name="external_files"
        path="."  /> <!-- consider changing this to more specific path-->
</paths>
```

Lastly, this is how I implemented it.

```
String nowDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";
            File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/"+"ExcelFile_"+nowDateTime+".xls");

            if(!filePath.exists()){
                filePath.createNewFile();
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            hssfWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);

            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getContext(),"com.example.counter", filePath);
            emailIntent.setType("application/excel");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.Email_Subject_Line));
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            this.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it worked for me as required, and it works on all android versions including 11,12, and 13 too.